# add contact to a group in Android

Tags: android

I am working on android apps. I want to add a contact in android phone group. The code I am using is below:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID,personId);

    values.put(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,GROUP_ID);

    values.put(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

    Log.d("values :", ""+ values);

    this.getContentResolver().insert(   
                 ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. Does anyone see anything obviously wrong with the above code?

Comment: I have edited your question, however you need to add an edit under mine to explain what, precisely isn't working. Does it blow up? Do you get an error, if so, what? You'll need to add this, or your question will very likely be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bellow code is worked perfect in my side. So, Please try it or you can download sample example from [chetanbhalala](https://github.com/chetanbhalala/Add-contact-to-group-in-android)

```
try
{

   // Add selected contact to selected group
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID,Integer.parseInt(245)); // 245 is a contact id, replace with selected contact id

       values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,3);// 3 is a group id, replace with selected group id

       values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

       ContextWrapper context = this;
       context.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
       // End add contact to group code
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
   // TODO: handle exception
   Log.d("add group error :", ""+ e.getMessage().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, fullname);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,phoneno);
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email);
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NOTES,
                        "Imported from moodle");
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, city
                        + " " + country);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (requestCode == 1) {

                }
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a issue in [chetanbhalala / Add-contact-to-group-in-android](https://github.com/chetanbhalala/Add-contact-to-group-in-android/issues) with selected item on click function.

i solved it like this way

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == btn_add)
    {
        if(selected_items_id.size() > 0)
        {
            selected_items_id.clear();
        }
        ListView parent = getListView();
        SparseBooleanArray choices = parent.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getCount(); i++)
        {                
            if (choices.get(i))
            {
                selected_items_id.add(""+ group_contacts_id.get(i));
                  System.out.println(group_contacts_id.get(i)+"group_contacts_id is");
            }  
        } 

        if(selected_items_id.size() > 0)
        {
            add_group();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "please select contact:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
public static void createNewGroup(String name)
    {
        try
    {
        ContentValues groupValues = new ContentValues();
        groupValues.put(Groups.TITLE, name);
        groupValues.put(Groups.SHOULD_SYNC, true);
        groupValues.put(Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE, 1);
        groupValues.putNull(Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        groupValues.putNull(Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME);
        getContentResolver().insert(Groups.CONTENT_URI, groupValues);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

2)

```
public static Uri addContactToGroup(String rawContactId,String groupId)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
            values.put(GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, groupId);
            values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

            return getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
        return Uri.EMPTY;
    }
```

3)

```
public static Cursor getContactGroupId(String contactId)
    {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] columns = new String[] { GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID };
        String where = Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] args = new String[] {contactId, GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
        return Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, where, arg, null);
    }
```

4)

```
public static Cursor getGroupsList(@Nullable String[] project,@Nullable String where,@Nullable String[] args,@Nullable String sort)
    {

        return getContentResolver().query(Groups.CONTENT_URI, project, where, args, sort);
    }
```