# How to add Contacts into Contact group in android

Tags: android

**Can i add contact directly in to contact groups. if it is possible share the code to me. also
       share the code insert into contact alone.**

Comment: Have you looked on the android developers site http://developer.android.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addContact(String DisplayName, String MobileNumber,
        String HomeNumber, String emailID, String WorkNumber, String company, String jobTitle) {

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());

    // ------------------------------------------------------ Names
    if (DisplayName != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        DisplayName).build());
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number
    if (MobileNumber != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        MobileNumber)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .build());
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
    if (HomeNumber != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        HomeNumber)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                .build());
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
    if (WorkNumber != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        WorkNumber)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------ Email
    if (emailID != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                        emailID)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------ Organization
    if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY,
                        company)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE,
                        jobTitle)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());
    }

    // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

You also need to Write_contacts permision in your manifest

Comment: thank you for your response. how can i  add this contacts in to particular group

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630665/add-contact-to-a-group-in-android)

Comment: once again thank you for your response. this time i have another doubt how can i  get contact id

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int getContactIDFromNumber(String contactNumber,Context context){
contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver()
    .query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.contactNumber),new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
       phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
        }
    contactLookupCursor.close();
return phoneContactID;}
```

This is how you get the contact id if you have a string containing the number.
Also you need permission for reading contacts for this.