# Add contact to a group in Android app

Tags: android

I am working on android apps. I want to add a contact in Android phone group. The code I am using is shown below but the group doesn't add to grouplist in phone:

```
    private void addContact(String name, String phone, String group) {

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                .build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phone)
                .build());
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE, 1)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, group)
                .build());

        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to look at this post [add contact to a group in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630665/add-contact-to-a-group-in-android)